# Moshi generic type adapter

Tags: java, android, gson, moshi

Suppose have the following parameterised data class representing a server response:

```
public class SocketResponse<T> {
    private String responseMessage;
    private int responseCode;
    private T entity;
}
```

I know at runtime what type T will be. does moshi support generic type adapter the same way Gson does? With Gson id do the following to parse this.

```
Type typeA = new TypeToken<SocketResponse<MyResponseA>>(){}.getType();
SocketResponse<MyResponseA> responseA = getResponse("json", typeA);

Type typeB = new TypeToken<SocketResponse<MyResponseB>>(){}.getType();
SocketResponse<MyResponseB> responseB = getResponse("json", typeB);


private String getResponse(Type t){
    return gson.fromJson(response, type);
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Moshi uses the factory methods on [Types](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/224369155eb4d806ba5afda8f192d004f9e3441d/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/Types.java) to get Java Types in contrast to Gson's TypeToken API.

```
Type typeA = Types.newParameterizedType(SocketResponse.class, MyResponseA.class);
JsonAdapter<SocketResponse<MyResponseA>> adapter = moshi.adapter(typeA);
```

Then, use the JsonAdapter to deserialize and serialize your type, just like Gson's TypeAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

Just for a more complex situation, if `T` equals a generic type like this `List<MyResponseA>`. you can do this for example (in `kotlin`):

```kotlin
val t = Types.newParameterizedType(
    SocketResponse::class.java, Types.newParameterizedType(
        List::class.java,
        MyResponseA::class.java
    )
)
val adapter = moshi.adapter<SocketResponse<List<MyResponseA>>>(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly using GSON but maybe something like that?

```
Type type = Types.newParameterizedType(SocketResponse.class, Object.class);
JsonAdapter<SocketResponse<?>> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(type);
```

Comment: Almost, but the parameter is MyResponseA or MyResponseB (not Object) in the example question.